# Least Common Multiple between "Operations Between Cells" values expressed in a list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to calculate the LCM between certain values, but since those values are the results of operations between cells and I wanted to occupy the least amount of cells I included the various operations directly into the LCM function.
It all works as long as I calculate the LCM only between two values, but I want it to calculate it between more than two and I want it to figure out the order of the cells in the operations.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZjFG.jpg For example here I want it to calculate the LCM between L2/M2+N2, L3/M3+N3,... and L27/M27+N27 but when I try to input this, it shows #N/D in the cell saying that the argument must be a range. My expected output would be to be able to have the LCM between L1-27/M1-27+N1-27 in a single cell without having that long list at O.

Are there any workarounds to do that?

Comment: Test data and expected output in tabular form would help us understand your question.

Comment: Added a more clear image and expected output.

Comment: Try this, it is not tested: `=LCM(INDEX((L2:L27/M2:M27+N2:N27),))`

Comment: I tried it and it gives a "Formula Parse Error", so I removed the unnecessary comma and parentheses ("=LCM(INDEX(L2:L27/M2:M27+N2:N27))" is the correct one) and it worked as a charm.
Put it as a proper answer and I'll accept it as most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) are for. First, you need to specify the ranges before each operator. Second you need to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter when you finish typing the formula. The resulting formula should look like this:

`{=LCM(L2:L27/M2:M27+N2:N27)}`

Entering with Ctrl-Shift-Enter automatically adds the braces.